# Random incremental timestamp in R

Tags: r

I want to generate a series of 500 TimeStamp starting Jan 1st, 2016 in such a way that the increment of time stamp should look like something as below.

**Sample:**

```
TimeStamp
2016-01-01 00:00:01
2016-01-01 00:00:12
2016-01-01 00:00:15
2016-01-01 00:01:23
2016-01-01 00:02:31
2016-01-01 00:02:38
2016-01-01 00:03:48
2016-01-01 00:03:55
.....
```

**What I am doing as of now is:**

```
SampleData <-  as.data.frame(list(Var1=1:500, Var2=rnorm(1, 500, 500)))

rDate <- function(sDate, eDate, SampleData){   
  lenDate <- dim(sampledata)[1]    
  seqDays <- seq.Date(as.Date(sDate), as.Date(eDate), by="day")  
  aDay <- runif(lenDate, 1, length(seqDays))  
  Date <- seqDays[aDay]  
}

SampleData$TimeStamp <- rDate("2016-01-01", "2016-12-31", SampleData)
SampleData <- SampleData[order(SampleData$TimeStamp), ]
row.names(SampleData) <- NULL
head(SampleData)
```

But this will produce the following **result**:

```
  Var1     Var2  TimeStamp
1  200 1020.469 2016-01-01
2  100 1020.469 2016-01-02
3  344 1020.469 2016-01-02
4  447 1020.469 2016-01-04
5  453 1020.469 2016-01-05
6  478 1020.469 2016-01-05
```

Which is not what I wanted.

Could someone please help?

Comment: for my project... i need such data

Comment: No. no conditions. just random time stamp with incremental order.

Comment: The simple solution is to generate a random time stamp and sort the time stamp.

Answer (score 1):

Just change `seq.Date` into `seq.POSIXt` and `as.Date` into `as.POSIXct`

```
SampleData <-  as.data.frame(list(Var1=1:500, Var2=rnorm(1, 500, 500)))

rDate <- function(sDate, eDate, SampleData){   
    lenDate <- dim(SampleData)[1]    
    seqDays <- seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(sDate), as.POSIXct(eDate), by="secs")  
    aDay <- runif(lenDate, 1, length(seqDays))  
    Date <- seqDays[aDay]  
}

SampleData$TimeStamp <- rDate("2016-01-01", "2016-12-31", SampleData)
SampleData <- SampleData[order(SampleData$TimeStamp), ]
row.names(SampleData) <- NULL
head(SampleData)

  Var1     Var2           TimeStamp
1   29 660.4593 2016-01-01 13:25:31
2  213 660.4593 2016-01-02 07:17:10
3  115 660.4593 2016-01-05 01:07:48
4  358 660.4593 2016-01-05 06:24:41
5  276 660.4593 2016-01-06 10:02:18
6   49 660.4593 2016-01-06 21:56:25
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like,

```
as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 00:00:00") + sort(sample(1:1000, 500))
```

We can check this for 5 samples

```
as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 00:00:00") + sort(sample(1:1000, 5))

#[1] "2016-01-01 00:01:53 IST" "2016-01-01 00:02:06 IST" "2016-01-01 00:03:19 IST"
#[4] "2016-01-01 00:07:31 IST" "2016-01-01 00:12:26 IST"
```

This will add randomly 1 to 1000 seconds in an incremental fashion in 1st of Jan 2016. To further increase the range we can increase the sequence from `1:1000` to any number you wish.

---

Another solution which takes advantage of entire range is

```
startTime <- as.POSIXct("2016-01-01")
endTime <- as.POSIXct("2016-12-31")
sample(seq(startTime, endTime, 1), 500)
```

Here we generate sequence for every second from our `startTime` to our `endTime` and then take random 500 values from it. Although, this is complete but this would become slow as the difference between `startTime` and `endTime` increases.

Answer (score 1):

Here I got something for you...

```
RandomTimeStamp <- function(M, sDate="2016/01/01", eDate="2016/12/31") {
sDate <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(sDate))
eDate <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(eDate))
dTime <- as.numeric(difftime(eDate, sDate, unit="sec"))
sTimeStamp <- sort(runif(M, 0, dTime))
TimeStamp <- sDate + sTimeStamp
}

print(RandomTimeStamp(500))
```

This produces the result as:

```
[1] "2012-01-01 18:26:53 IST" "2012-01-02 11:35:47 IST" "2012-01-02 15:02:23 IST" "2012-01-02 19:19:25 IST"
  [5] "2012-01-03 04:48:13 IST" "2012-01-03 21:05:42 IST" "2012-01-03 21:16:06 IST" "2012-01-04 21:05:08 IST"
  [9] "2012-01-05 05:47:13 IST" "2012-01-05 06:27:44 IST" "2012-01-05 06:40:42 IST" "2012-01-05 21:56:45 IST"
 [13] "2012-01-06 22:36:40 IST" "2012-01-07 03:48:37 IST" "2012-01-07 12:55:25 IST" "2012-01-07 20:52:19 IST" .........
```

You might want to tweak around the code... :)

Comment: this is better as i can create a different column and just add back to my original dataframe. thanks.